# Simplest way to extend Dashcode components?

Tags: events, dashcode, extending-classes

I'm presently working on a project in Dashcode, and am getting increasingly frustrated at how the default classes have very little in the way of bind-able events much like jQuery uses. Dashcode doesn't let me edit the files, which I'm guessing is because until the project is exported they're a standard set of core classes. I'm thus contemplating extending the classes, but am unsure how Dashcode relates a component to a class.

Any ideas how best to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0):

"Dashcode doesn't let me edit the files," you don't specify which files but you may need to switch CodeGenerator off else dashcode will revert and regenerate code you change.

You might want to look at [sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) as they do a more comprehensive framework for this sort of thing. There are many other frameworks out there as well.

Comment: Hi There,

The way I was meaning was the general files such as modifying the behaviour of a datasource or component (the list view in a browser, for example). I believe these are compiled into parts.js and minified to some extent. I know I could just not minify them, but still there are questions over exactly the best point at which to modify the code.